# Finding a Linear Equation With n solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, congruences

The goal is to find an integer $m$ and a linear equation in $\mod m$ such that there are three solutions.  My thought is that I would want $m = 3$, but I don't know where to go from here.  Tips or an example with a different number of solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: How many variables do you allow in the equation?

Comment: I suppose just two variables.

Comment: Okay, try writing down a simple linear equation in two variables mod $m=3$ and count the solutions

Comment: I was in the process of answering [your question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153230/non-linear-congruence-equation) Could you please undelete it.

Comment: Sorry about that!

Comment: @user2049004 Thanks, let me know if anything is not clear there.

Answer (score 1):

$$0x=0\mod 3,$$

solve for $x$.

If you want something a little more "non-trivial", you could write:

$$4x=7x\mod 3.$$

Comment: If we wished to have two variables as in the Comments, then $x\equiv y \mod 3$ works.